# Проблема объявления дружественной функции другим классом

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы, дружественная-функция

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;`

class hospital;
class patient
{
friend void hospital::get_ill_patients(); // Вот тут выдаёт ошибку 2027
private:
    ...
    int name;
public:
    ...
};

class hospital
{
private:
    patient patients_data; 
public:

   void get_ill_patients()//Вот этот метод и должен получить доступ к private полям класса patient
   {
        if(patients_data.name...) // Вот для такой примерно проверки и требуется доступ 
        {

        }
   }    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не должны использовать ничего, кроме ссылок/указателей на не полностью определенный класс. В строке

```
friend void hospital::get_ill_patients();
```

ничего не известно о существовании функции `get_ill_patients()`.

Или делайте дружественным весь класс

```
friend class hospital;
```

или немного меняйте саму структуру - например, делайте

```
patient patients_data;
```

указателем или ссылкой, меняйте местами объявления и выносите определение фнкции-члена из класса, что-то вроде

```
class patient;

class hospital
{
private:
    patient * patients_data;
public:

    void get_ill_patients();
};


class patient
{
    friend void hospital::get_ill_patients();
    private:
        int name;
    public:
};

void hospital::get_ill_patients()
{
    if(patients_data->name)
    {

    }
}
```